# Generate and graph the Recamán Sequence

Tags: generative-art, integer-sequence

I was surprised to see that we don't have any posts that mention the [Recamán Sequence](https://oeis.org/A005132), so I figured I should post it as a challenge. By definition, $a_0=0$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}-n$ if the r.h.s. is positive and different from all previous elements, and $a_n=a_{n-1}+n$ otherwise. The first few terms are `0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11, 22, ...`.

How can we generate this sequence as concisely as possible? And how to represent it graphically? An example of a possible representation is (source: [Numberphile](https://youtu.be/4TK_raXODbo))

[image]

where each half-circle represents the jump from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$. It could be interesting to add colour. Extra points if you come up with an alternative representation which is aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: OEIS calls  it "Recaman sequence", not "Recaman Sequence".

Comment: @user64494 No, it calls it Recam**á**n ;-)

Comment: @user64494 Please stop these micro-edits. They don't improve the quality of the question and I'm sure we can agree that everyone can interpret the title.

Comment: @hairutan: Of course, I must listen to the forum moderators and I will listen to them. Do you treat a correction of grammar mistakes (not in this case) as micro-edit?

Comment: @user64494 No, *usually*, I welcome even small edits that improve the grammar. However, in this case, you changed **graph** to **Graph** 2 times without knowing that it is a verb here: "to graph -- to draw (a curve) as representing a given function". Secondly, Recamán Sequence *could* be regarded as a proper noun like *House of Representatives*. Even when most sources write sequence in lower case, the readers would have no problem to understand it. The title of this question has 7 edits and this simply escalates things and isn't helpful at all. Why don't you use this time to answer some Qs?

Answer (score 18):

My own take on this:

```
Clear[f]
f[0] = 0;
f[n_] := f[n] = If[Or[MemberQ[Last /@ Most[DownValues[f]], f[n - 1] - n], 
f[n - 1] < n], f[n - 1] + n, f[n - 1] - n]

f /@ Range[0, 11]
(* {0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11, 22} *)
```

We can draw the figure using

```
With[{list = Table[f[n], {n, 0, 30}]},
     Show[Graphics@*Circle @@@ Partition[Flatten[{
     MovingAverage[Transpose[{list, Table[0, Length[list]]}], 2],
     Abs[Differences[list]/2],
     Partition[Range[Length[list]] \[Pi], 2, 1]
     }, {2, 1}], 3], ImageSize -> Full]
]
```

[image]

We can even add some colour using

```
Show[With[{list = Table[f[n], {n, 0, 30}]},
     Show[Graphics[{Opacity[.2], ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#[[1, 1]]/50], #}] &@*Disk @@@ Partition[Flatten[{
     MovingAverage[Transpose[{list, Table[0, Length[list]]}], 2],
     Abs[Differences[list]/2],
     Partition[Range[Length[list]] \[Pi], 2, 1]
     }, {2, 1}], 3]]
], %, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: I haven’t looked too hard at this code yet, but any reason you did not let it populate to at least the OP’s example? I wonder if there are other ways to plot the integer steps!!!! And how we might automate this  looks like I know how I’ll be distracting myself tonight!

Answer (score 17):

Just the visualization part using `ParametricPlot`:

```
recamanSequencePlot1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[Map[RotationTransform[Pi/4] @ 
      {Mean @ # + (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 Cos[t], (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 Sin[t]} &,
     Partition[#, 2, 1]]], 
   {t, 0, -Pi}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large] &;
```

Using AccidentalFourierTransform's `f` to generate a sequence of length `k`:

```
k = 30;
list = Table[f[n], {n, 0, k}]; 
recamanSequencePlot1 @ list
```

[image]

With `k = 100` we get

[image]

To get the fillings we can use two-parameter form of `ParametricPlot`:

```
recamanSequencePlot2 = ParametricPlot[ 
   Evaluate[Map[RotationTransform[Pi/4] @ 
      {Mean @ # + (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 Cos[t] r, (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 Sin[t] r} &,
     Partition[#, 2, 1]]], 
   {t, 0, -Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None,  PlotStyle -> 
  Opacity[.2], BoundaryStyle -> None] &;

Show[recamanSequencePlot1[list], recamanSequencePlot2[list]]
```

[image]

In the pictures above the increases in the sequence are shown below the diagonal and decreases above the diagonal to distinguish them visually.  Change the first argument of `ParametricPlot` to

```
Evaluate[Module[{k = 1}, Map[RotationTransform[Pi/4] @ 
  {Mean @ # +(k=-k)Abs[#[[2]] - #[[1]]]/2 Cos[  t],k   Abs[#[[2]] - #[[1]]]/2 Sin[ t]} &,
     Partition[#, 2, 1]]]]
```

to replicate the picture in OP:

[image]

... and variations using `BSplineCurve`:

```
 Graphics[{ColorData[97][RandomInteger[{1, Length@list}]], AbsoluteThickness[4],
   BSplineCurve[#]} &@{{#, 0}, {#, Subtract@##}, {#2, Subtract @ ##}, {#2, 0}} & @@@ 
      Partition[list, 2, 1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{ColorData[97][RandomInteger[{1, Length @ list}]], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
  BSplineCurve[#, SplineDegree -> 1]} & @
     {{#, 0}, {Mean@{##}, 1/2 Subtract@##}, {#2, 0}} & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate[Table[
  Graphics[{Hue[#[[2, 2]]/100], Opacity[.75], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
   BSplineCurve[#, SplineDegree -> 1]} &@{{#, 0}, {Mean@{##}, 1/2 Subtract@##}, {#2, 0}} & 
    @@@ Partition[list[[;; t]], 2, 1], 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 250}, {-50, 50}}], {t, 2, 100}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

If you don't care about extra space, we can employ a reverse lookup table:

```
seenQ[0] = True;
a[0] = 0;
a[n_] := a[n] = With[{prev = a[n - 1]},
  (seenQ[#] = True; #) &[
    If[prev > n && ! TrueQ[seenQ[prev - n]], prev - n, prev + n]
  ]
]

Block[{$RecursionLimit = ∞},
  Do[a[k], {k, 10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
]
```

> ```
> {8.55911, Null}
> ```

```
a /@ Range[0, 20]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11, 22, 10, 23, 9, 24, 8, 25, 43, 62, 42}
> ```

---

If you know the largest value of the sequence you'd like to compute, we can pre allocate the tables and therefore also compile. This gives us more than a 100 times speedup:

```
RecamanTable = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Module[{seenQ = Table[0, {8n}], as = Table[0, {n+1}], prev = 0},
    seenQ[[1]] = 1;
    Do[
      If[prev > k && Compile`GetElement[seenQ, prev-k+1] == 0,
        prev -= k,
        prev += k
      ];
      seenQ[[prev+1]] = 1;
      as[[k+1]] = prev;, 
      {k, 1, n}
    ];
    as
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

RecamanTable[10^8]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.97308, Null}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I have a few experiments to contribute:

1. I tried to fill the gaps and use up all the "unused" integers in a Recamán series truncated to N entries, so whenever a member of the series is bigger than N, it just jumps to the first integer that is not part of the series yet. Also, I added a final semicircle that connects the last and the first entry to close the loop:

```
f[0] = 0;
f[n_] := f[n] = If[Or[MemberQ[Last /@ Most[DownValues[f]], f[n - 1] - n], 
    f[n - 1] < n], f[n - 1] + n, f[n - 1] - n]
n = 15;
(*generate series*)
rec = (f /@ Range[0, n]);
(*look for unused Integers*)
unu =  If[Position[rec, #] == {}, #, Nothing] & /@ Range[n];
(*look for entries > N*)
upo = Flatten[Position[If[# > n, NaN, #] & /@ rec, NaN]]; 
red = rec;
(*replace entries > N with unused Integers*)
(red = ReplacePart[red, upo[[#]] ->(*Reverse[*)unu(*]*)[[#]]]) &/@
Range[Min[Length[unu],Length[upo]]];
red = Append[red, 0];
```

```
lpt = Range[n + 1];
crc = Circle[{(lpt[[red[[# + 1]] + 1]] - lpt[[red[[#]] + 1]])/2 + 
       lpt[[red[[#]] + 1]], 0}, 
     Abs[(lpt[[red[[# + 1]] + 1]] - lpt[[red[[#]] + 1]])/2], 
     If[EvenQ[#], {0, Pi}, {Pi, 2*Pi}]] & /@ Range[n + 1];
g2 = Graphics[Flatten[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 1], crc}], 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: N=15]

[image: N=105]

2. I mapped all the points onto a cricle and connected them with straight lines instead of semicircles (this also makes use of 1.)

```
p = 2*Pi/n;
pts = If[p*# < Pi/2 || p*# > 3/2*Pi, {Cos[p*#], 
      Sin[p*#]}, {-Cos[Pi - p*#], Sin[Pi - p*#]}] & /@ Range[0, n];
lns = {pts[[red[[#]] + 1]], pts[[red[[# + 1]] + 1]]} & /@ Range[n - 1];
g1 = Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 1], Line[Flatten[lns, 1]]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: N=15]

[image: N=105]

[image: N=1005]

3. There's a pattern that emerges when you just ListPlot the Series:

[image]